# Project not working after Maven build

Tags: spring, maven, maven-2, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am working in a Spring Legacy Project.It has a pom.xml file.Project works and deploys fine without the maven clean and install.But after maven build,the name of the war changes and the application is not up again.

The tool is Spring Suite Tool and the server is Jboss.

Please help me on this.

Comment: *"name of the war changes"* - from what? *to* what? Did you set `finalName` in your pom.xml?

Comment: can you paste your pom here